# Parametric curve and its orientation

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am having trouble understanding how to find the orientation of the graph of the curve.
I plotted the two equations on Wolfram Alpha (see picture of graph above). Where should I be drawing the arrows on the graph to show the orientation? Thank you!

Comment: Check where you on the curve are when $\;t=0\,,\;t=2\,,\;t=4\,,\;t=8\;$ , and etc.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that now. Can I notify you my answer once I'm done?

Comment: If you have a parametrization $c(t)$, fix any $t_0$ and compute the derivative $c'(t_0)$. Place this vector at the point $c(t_0)$. The tangent vector points in the direction the curve goes.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of parametrization for a curve can change its orientation. There are common ones, say for the circle $\langle \cos t, \sin t \rangle$, which you can remember is oriented counterclockwise starting at $(1,0)$ with this choice. But for a generic curve, you will have to choose a particular $t$ value and see what happens as you vary $t$, i.e. does the $x,y$ coordinate increase/decrease for a 'small' change in $t$, using derivatives or 'derivative' estimates if the derivative does not exist. If the curve is simple, plotting might be easier. Plot for a few $t$ values with $t$ consistently increasing/decreasing to see what happens.

For your example, notice that as $t \to \infty$, both $x,y \to \infty$ so the curve most 'move upwards' and 'to the right'.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim_{t\to \pm\infty} \frac {y(t)}{x(t)}=1$, which indicates the slope of the orientation, i.e. at 45 degrees with the $x$-axis.